# Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, appinsights

I am using .net core 3.1 function app and implemented app insight. Error is logging good and I am able to see it in azure portal app insight but receiving below error when trying to log information.

> AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore] ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore : An instance of EventSource with Guid dbf4c9d9-6cb3-54e3-0a54-9d138a74b116 already exists.
>
> How to write information logs to azure app insight.
> I have already tried many stackoverflow and MS suggestions. Even tried updating app insight version fron 2.17.0 to 2.19.0. Nothing worked.

local.settings.json

```
"values" :{
         "INSTRUMENTATION_KEY": "*******************",
   },
  "logging": {
"logLevel": {
  "default": "Information",
  "Function": "Information",
  "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
  "Host.Results": "Error"
}
}
```

host.json

```
  {
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
  "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
  "samplingSettings": {
    "isEnabled": false
  }
}
}
}
```

startup.cs

```
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
      {
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        // Add and Configure Application Insight
        builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("INSTRUMENTATION_KEY"));
       }
```

Function:

```
public class TestFunction
{
  private readonly ILogger<TestFunction> _log;

   public TestFunction(ILogger<TestFunction> log)
   {
       _log = log;
   }

    [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%RUN_SCHEDULE%")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {

       _log.LogInformation("I am not working :("); //Log is not written to azure app insight
       _log.LogError("Yipee I am working"); //Able to see error logs in app insgight
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore] ERROR: Exception in Command Processing for EventSource Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-AspNetCore : An instance of EventSource with Guid dbf4c9d9-6cb3-54e3-0a54-9d138a74b116 already exists.

is unrelated to the fact that you cannot see the telemetry with severity level `Information`.

Per default AI only logs telemetry with severity `Warning` or higher. To change that you need to specify the log level of the AI category like this:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
      "Host.Results": "Error"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "************"
  }
}
```